# Unable to load data from JSON

Tags: ajax, json

I want to load json data from js file (url:'myTurorials.json' throwing error so I used .js,)

Please give me solution, thanks in advance.

```js
code from 'myTurorials.js' file is as bellow
`[
{"display": "JavaScript Tutorial", "url":"http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"},
{"display": "HTML Tutorial", "url":"http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"},
{"display": "CSS Tutorial", "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"}
]`
code from 'myTurorials.js' ends here

$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $.ajax({
   type : 'GET',
   url : 'myTutorials.js',
   dataType : 'json',
   contentType : 'application/json',
   success: function (response) {
    alert('success');    
   },
   error : function(){
    alert('error');
   },
   complete : function(){
    //init();
   }
  });
});

function init(){
 myFunction(myArray);
}

function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>HTML5 responsive website tutorial</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>

<!-- my files -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="id01"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your code and think about what's happening. What do you presume `myFunction(myArray)` does? Where's `myArray`? Your data is contained in the `response` variable passed to your `success` function, and you do nothing there. You have to do something with that data; it won't just magically insert itself into `myArray`.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - That is what I want to know, what should I write so I can get the correct ans, just ignore the "myFunction(myArray)", I was trying to create a myArray object in the "myTurorials.js" file & calling it through the myFunction

var myArray = [
{"display": "JavaScript Tutorial", "url":"http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp"},
{"display": "HTML Tutorial", "url":"http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp"},
{"display": "CSS Tutorial", "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp"}
]

Comment: @ChristianVarga - I am a not a coder but want to learn it, so whenever I stuck to any issue I tried to solve my self then put it here for help. I don't want someone write code for me, just need help to understand the coding part.